# Hadoop Hive TEZ task fails (to start container)

Tags: hadoop, hive, tez

Ive got hadoop-2.8.3, hive-2.3.2, and tez (trying out 0.9 and 0.8.5 versions).
tez-site basic conf:

- tez.lib.uris: /apps/tez/apache-tez-0.8.5-bin.tar.gz (uploaded to hdfs)
- tez.use.cluster.hadoop-libs: false

Container log stderr shows:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster
```

YARN resource manager tracking shows:

```
Application application_1516872625165_0011 failed 2 times due to AM 
Container for appattempt_1516872625165_0011_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1516872625165_0011_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchC    ontainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:236)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.Contai    nerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:84)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http[...snip]
```

So, containers fails twice when it cant find/load the DAGAppMaster class. What am i forgetting?

Comment: You need to check the Tez or YARN UI for those tasks that failed

Comment: @cricket_007 the quoted stuff is exactly that.

Comment: Ah, was looking at the bottom block from the AM

Answer (score 0):

So, the apache-tez-0.8.5-bin.tar.gz tarball is not the correct one to use. Inside of it, theres another archive - share/tez.tar.gz - and this one has to uploaded and referenced in tez site.